# monitor slow query metrics for mongodb exporter provided by Percona, but not able to find the right metrics

Tags: database, mongodb, prometheus, grafana, percona

I'm trying to monitor slow query metrics for mongodb exporter provided by Percona, but not able to find the right metrics. can anyone guide me how can we get this?

Link the mongodb exporter releases
https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter/releases/tag/v2.37.0

I tested with multiple released version but not able to identify the right metrics for identifying slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this exporter provide slow query metrics currently.
Found another exporter: https://github.com/stutzlab/mongo-simple-exporter which will create slow queries metrics from logs:

> //get logs in order to look at slow queries and other important clues
> db.adminCommand( { getLog: "global" } )

Comment: https://github.com/stutzlab/mongo-simple-exporter
Above exporter don't have any binaries, i have tested above exporter, Is there any other way we can test slow queries